# How do I handle escape character in parameter arguments in Python?

Tags: python, escaping, command-line-arguments

> skript parameter: "C:\Ordner 1\" "D:\test 2\"

As you can see the parameter arguments given above are two paths ...

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:    
    print(sys.argv[1])
    print(sys.argv[2])
```

The result is:

```
C:\Users\Joss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe E:/test.py "C:\Ordner 1\" D:\test" 2\"
C:\Ordner 1" D:\test
2"
```

You can see this is a mess !
What I would like to see should be:

```
C:\Ordner 1\ 
D:\test 2\
```

How do I get Python to do it right? Python should ignore the escape characters in the parameter arguments!
To use other parameter arguments isn't an option!

Comment: Your command line should be: C:\Users\Joss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe E:/test.py "C:\Ordner 1" "D:\test 2"

Comment: What happens if you double the last backslash of each argument?

Answer (score 0):

You escape the `"` char with `\"`. Also wrap the whole argument with `"..."`:

Try this:

```
python.exe test.py "C:\\Ordner 1" "D:\\test 2"
```

or

```
python.exe test.py "C:/Ordner 1" "D:/test 2"
```

Comment: This doesn't work :(

Comment: @JKR I updated my answer. And plz explain "doesn't work".. result??

Comment: I know the fact about the escape characters. My issue is that Python should not change the input string - here the parameter arguments!

When the paramter is "c:\Ordner 1\" then I will get  in python  the string : 
 c:\Ordner 1\

Character replacements are not permitted!

Comment: And as I wrote above ... "To use other parameter arguments isn't an option!"

Comment: @JKR what do you mean by "use other parameter arguments isn't an option"? You can't customize the arguments? then you have a bad chance to solve it... If you find a solution let me know ;) - by the way this is not a python problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I have now found out, it is not a Python problem. The console also works with escape characters, which means that the string is not passed on as I assumed.

A work around for me whould be the following:
"C:\Ordner 1\ " "D:\test 2\ "
... a space between \ and "